# Why does this example of what compilers aren't allowed to do cause null pointer dereferencing using cmov?

Tags: c, assembly, x86

C code:

```
int cread(int *xp) {
    return (xp ? *xp : 0);
}
```

assembly code: (from a textbook example of what a compiler isn't allowed to do) using conditional move instruction

```
movl    $0, %eax
testl   %edx, %edx
cmovne  (%edx), %eax
```

This is an example used in *Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective* (2nd edition) to show that code cannot be compiled using conditional data transfer if either branch of a condition results in an error. In this case, the error would be the null pointer dereferencing of xp.

I understand that xp is dereferenced, but I don't understand how xp becomes a null pointer. Wouldn't that depend on pointer being passed as a parameter into the function?

Comment: Yes, it can only be `NULL` if it's passed in as parameter. But the whole point of the code is to check for a `NULL` and in that case return zero. The `cmov` version fails to do this, as it will always try to dereference the pointer, so it will fault instead of returning zero.

Comment: There's something misleading about this question. I don't think the assembly code shown was actually generated by gcc as claimed. If it was, it's a compiler bug.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley : You are correct. The assembly code from the book actually says `Invalid implementation of function cread
xp in register %edx` as a preface to invalid example code (the piece the OP has shown us). It wasn't generated by gcc as this OP suggests.

Comment: it looks to me that it match. because of `movl 0,eax` instead of xoring eax ?

Comment: `cmov[cc] (mem), %reg` is not an Itanium-style speculative load. The load is performed *unconditionally*, only the value of the destination register is predicated.

Comment: @MichaelPetch and Wumpus: Editted the OP's question to remove the incorrect statement that it was gcc output.  Good catch.

Comment: @Jester : I'm hoping I can understand your answer (and my mistake as revealed by Wumpus Q. Wumbley and Michael Petch) well enough to restate it. Basically, the assembly code is not valid because the passed pointer _might_ be NULL, and the compiler wouldn't allow such a possibility because that pointer would be dereferenced anyway in this particular implementation. Is this accurate?

Answer (score 4):

The assembly code is technically valid, but it would fault if the input was `NULL` and as such doesn't match the behavior of the C code. Given that the whole point of the thing is to return zero in that case and not fault, it's wrong. The C equivalent is:

```
int cread(int *xp) {
    int val = *xp;
    return (xp ? val : 0);
}
```

As you can see, it first dereferences `xp` and only then checks to see if `xp` is `NULL` so this clearly won't work for `NULL` input.

Comment: I think the code is valid. CSAPP 3e has changed this part of code.

Comment: Amusingly, but not surprisingly, GCC and ICC both compile the C code you show into a simple `mov  eax, [rdi]`.

Comment: Related: [Hard to debug SEGV due to skipped cmov from out-of-bounds memory](//stackoverflow.com/q/54050188) explains more about how `cmov` is an ALU select operation that always needs both operands, unlike ARM predicated loads, or Itanium speculative loads.

Answer (score 2):

If you make the call

```
cread(0);
```

The `cmovene` instruction will seg fault because it evaluates `*xp` even though the value will never be used.

In the assembly language, this is expressed by `(%edx)`.  I.e. the contents of memory at the address in `%edx` are loaded regardless of the value of `edx`.

The value of `cmov` has been called into question generally. For example [Linus Torvalds](http://yarchive.net/comp/linux/cmov.html) is not a fan.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that xp is dereferenced, but I don't understand how xp becomes a null pointer. Wouldn't that depend on pointer being passed as a parameter into the function?

You're technically correct (and the textbook technically wrong - in theory, in some circumstances, the compiler could legally generate that code).

However; the circumstances where that code can be generated are:

a) the compiler (and/or linker) can prove that no caller ever passes NULL to the function. In this case the compiler also proves that the `cmov` is pointless and can be replaced with a normal store (a `mov` without any previous test).

b) the compiler (and/or linker) knows that referencing NULL in assembly (which is not C and does not need to follow the rules of C) is fine. Typically NULL in C is the address 0x00000000 in assembly, and typically the area at address 0x000000 is deliberately made inaccessible to help catch bugs; but there's no reason why an OS or a program can't make the area at 0x0000000 accessible (e.g. often it's trivial to do this just using a linker script).